# VeraCrypt Encrypt Windows System Partition with commandline

Tags: windows, veracrypt

I would like to use only the command line to encrypt my system using VeraCrypt
https://www.makeuseof.com/encrypt-windows-system-drive-veracrypt/
This is the tutorial I followed using the gui, now I'd like to try it using just the command line, how would I do this?